# Azure Container Instance IP

Tags: azure, service-discovery

I've created an Azure container instance with a Private IP. This is connected to a VNET so my Web Apps can communicate with it in a secure way. (This API has Bearer tokens also but I don't want to make it public).

However, when restarting the Container I get a new IP. Therefore I have to update the Env and restart my apps.

Is there a way to implement service discovery within Azure, so my Web Apps (and other services) know where this Container Instance is, especially when the container gets a new IP.

I am used to dealing with Pivotal and Consul but under Azure I don't have these tools.
In Pivotal I was able to fire up multiple instances and the platform would auto discover and load balance. At the moment, Azure feels very manual :(

- Does azure have the ability to register a service under a host name that can then auto resolve?
- Does Azure support load balancing when multiple instances are started with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of work maybe the best solution is to create an Azure service web app. The web app as public static IP link to your plan which does not change.
[Inbound and outbound IP addresses in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips)

With this solution your IP never change.
According to the documentation linked, you can find your inbound IP like this:

```powershell
nslookup <app-name>.azurewebsites.net
```

and the outbound IP in powershell:

```powershell
(Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroup <group_name> -name <app_name>).OutboundIpAddresses
```